# ECLIPSE RCP app: toolbar implementation

Tags: eclipse, toolbar, rcp, tableviewer

I have a view with custom toolbar with buttons such as first record, next record, previous record,etc.
I want to implement this functionality. I have command object for the toolbar buttons. How can I pass the info about which row is the current row on the table viewer? How the focus be moved to the next record if I select next record button on the tool bar?

Answer (score 0):

Access current row:

```
int currentSelectionPosition=tableViewer.getTable().getSelectionIndex();
```

Set selection on next row

```
tableViewer.getTable().select(currentSelectionPosition+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure that the `TableViewer` is the selection provider for your view:

```
getSite().setSelectionProvider(tableViewer);
```

This notifies the selection service of your workbench window every time the selected row in your table changes. The selection contains the model object that corresponds to the selected row.

In your command handler, you can get the current selection by calling

```
HandlerUtil.getCurrentSelectionChecked(executionEvent)
```

To move the focus in your `TableViewer` when the next button is pressed, you have to implement a public method in your view that increases the selection index of the underlying `Table` by one. To enable your command handler to call this method, you need to get the instance of the view. A quick-and-dirty solution would be to get the current part by calling

```
HandlerUtil.getActivePartChecked(executionEvent)
```

and cast the returned `IWorkbenchPart` to your view class.